# Undefined variable: image_event_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, undefined

I am receiving the following error - Notice: Undefined variable: image_event_id on line 68

The image_event_id variable is current blank, how do i check the variable?

```
<?php    

    $eventID = $_REQUEST['event_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id='$eventID'";
    $queryresult = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    $image_sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE event_id='$eventID'";
    $image_queryresult = mysql_query($image_sql) or die (mysql_error());

    // Retrieve Event Variables
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
        $event_name = $row['event_name'];

        // Retrieve Image Variables
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_queryresult)) {
            $image_url = $row2['image_url'];
            $image_event_id = $row2['event_id'];
        }

    }

?>
```

Adding isset() doesn't seem to fix the error

Comment: Use `empty()` instead of `isset()`

Comment: Your code is very easily open to mysql injection attack. Please use PDO or mysqli to do the above.

Comment: to check what is actually contains use var_dump($_REQUEST['event_id']);

Comment: Which line is line 68?

Comment: line 68 is where i am calling the variable

if ($eventID == $image_event_id) {

Comment: So show it in context. You cannot not add the code with the line the "error" appears at ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in the top of your script.

```
$image_event_id = NULL;
```

Your second query is most likely not run and the variable is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id='$eventID'";
```

and

```
$image_sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE event_id='$eventID'";
```

are wrong because `event_id` should be an integer? If so you should remove the single qoutes like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id=$eventID";
```

This(below) never gets called because there is no results to iterate from

```
    // Retrieve Image Variables
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_queryresult)) {
        $image_url = $row2['image_url'];
        $image_event_id = $row2['event_id'];
    }
```

You are telling it to set $image_event_id while there are results, if there is none that block gets ignored completely thus making the line `$image_event_id` undefined.

So first make sure your query has results. Not only the query but also that your `$eventID` actually contains data.